# how to configure quartz scheduler to take up the stored jobs in database and execute on server restart?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, quartz-scheduler

I have been using quartz scheduler to shoot out bulk emails on hourly basis, which is working absolutely fine. This scheduler is explicitly called once. The problem arises when server restarts in the middle of the scheduler execution. Though quartz scheduler creates a record in the JOB_DETAILS table but doesn't take up the task to execute automatically when server starts.

Any help to resolve this is appreciated.

Here are the sample codes and current configuration.

```
SchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    Scheduler scheduler;
    try {
        scheduler = factory.getScheduler();

        // Creating Job and link to our Job class
        JobDetailImpl jobDetail = new JobDetailImpl();
        jobDetail.setName(jobName);
        jobDetail.setJobClass(HelloJob.class);


        int repeat = totalBal/Constants.HOURLY_LIMIT;
        System.out.println("totalBal : "+totalBal+ " | "+ "repeat : "+repeat);
        // Creating schedule time with trigger
        SimpleTriggerImpl simpleTrigger = new SimpleTriggerImpl();
        simpleTrigger.setStartTime(new Date(
                System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000));
        simpleTrigger.setRepeatCount(repeat); // SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY
        //simpleTrigger.setRepeatInterval(3600000);
        simpleTrigger.setRepeatInterval(5000);
        simpleTrigger.setName(jobName);

        // Start scheduler
        System.out.println("Scheduler Started");
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.getContext().put("externalInstance", cmpgId);
        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, simpleTrigger);

    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
```

Quartz Properties file

```
# Configure ThreadPool  

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 25
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5

# Configure JobStore  

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
#org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_

# Configure Datasources  

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:mysql://10.10.10.131:3306/abc
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = product
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = product
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 5
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validationQuery=select 1
```

web.xml

```
...<context-param>
     <param-name>quartz:config-file</param-name>
     <param-value>quartz.properties</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
     <param-name>quartz:shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
     <param-name>quartz:wait-on-shutdown</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
     <param-name>quartz:start-on-load</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>

<servlet> 
  <servlet-name>QuartzInitializer</servlet-name> 
  <servlet-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet</servlet-class> 
  <init-param>

    <param-name>shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>

</servlet> ....
```

Comment: which version of quartz are you using?

Comment: I am using quartz-2.2.1.jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouln't use the constructor of concrete `JobDetail`/`Trigger` but use the builder classes `JobBuilder`and `TriggerBuilder` instead. There you can set the [`reqeustRecovery`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/JobBuilder.html#requestRecovery(boolean)) property, which

> [i]nstructs the Scheduler whether or not the Job should be re-executed
>   if a 'recovery' or 'fail-over' situation is encountered

```
JobDetail job = newJob(MyJob.class)
                   .withIdentity("myJob")
                   .requestRecovery(true)
                   .build();
```